# Color Scheme Plugin JAR file cant be imported, but individual files inside jar can be imported

Tags: intellij-idea, jar, color-scheme, intellij-plugin, intellij-icls

I am a developer of an IntelliJ Plugin. It is a color scheme where I only change the editor colors (not the colors of the IDE). I originally had only one color scheme file for my whole plugin (one `.icls` file), and that code is live and working online.

Recently, I updated my color scheme to include two additional color schemes, which meant I had to add two new `.icls` files. This works on my local IDE that I am developing on; however, when I tested the finished plugin, the new instance of IntelliJ IDEA CE cannot extract the content from the new files.

### Problem

I need a **working JAR file that I can upload into the JetBrain Plugin Repository**; however, I cannot create a working Jar file anymore.

**Note: I am not looking to import a color scheme. I am a developer of a color scheme that needs to upload my plugin into the Jetbrain Plugin Repository**

When I **tested** the Color Scheme through `build`, `deploy`, and `run`, the new instance of the IDE will fail to find any color scheme. I cannot seem to narrow down why the IDE cannot load the color scheme; however, I was able to do the following...

- From the deployed JAR file, **rename** the file to be a **zip file**
- Extract the content of the zip file
- then...
- try `Settings >> Editor >> Color Scheme >> Import Scheme... >> Settings (.jar)` and find the **JAR file**. Nothing happens. No color schemes were imported.

...but...

- try `Settings >> Editor >> Color Scheme >> Import Scheme... >> IntelliJ IDEA color scheme (.icls)` and find each of the **.icls files**. Each individual color scheme is successfully found and loaded into the IDE.

### Additional Information

Originally, I was receiving the following issue [that I filed in JetBrain's Issue Tracker](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000444230-ERROR-rationStore-ComponentStoreImpl-Cannot-read-scheme-from-?page=1#community_comment_115000355790). However, after some tinkering, I was receiving a different set of issues. So, I started a new project and just copied the source files and plugin.xml file into the new project. Built, Deployed, and tested. No errors, no warnings (that I saw), but the color schemes are still not being loaded into the IDE.

Comment: Note: renaming `.icls` files to `.xml` allows me to run the plugin and find my color schemes, but there are some color incompatibility is incorrect. I believe these files SHOULD remain as `.icls` files

Answer (score -1):

File -> Import Settings -> select settings file.

In the settings file: top-level dir `colors` where `.icls` files located.

Comment: I am making a plugin. The user will go and browser the plugin repository in IntelliJ IDEA and select ChroMATERIAL. It is currently at v1.1.1; I have the code for v1.2 ready to release to the public. But when I deploy the plugin, the JAR file does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Cristopher, currently color schemes are supposed to be imported from settings.jar created  by Intellij IDEA upon File|Export Settings. The file has a certain structure, namely a 'colors' subdirectory with .icls files inside it. The IDE doesn't scan for other places where the files might reside.
If you create a plug-in, your users simply install it as a regular plugin, not importing any schemes. The difference is that these schemes become bundled. It means when a user makes changes to them, he can always revert to original color settings.

Comment: I am making a plugin. The user will go and browser the plugin repository in IntelliJ IDEA and select ChroMATERIAL. It is currently at v1.1.1; I have the code for v1.2 ready to release to the public. But when I deploy the plugin, the JAR file does not work. It is named ChroMATERIAL.jar and this is what is already available in v1.1.1. The problem is that this jar file is now (v1.2) not working but it worked for v1.1.1